# From a list of tuples [(ID, date),(ID, date)..] create a new list of tuples with unique ID and most recent date

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples [(ID,date),(ID,date),...]. The same ID can occur many times or only once. If ID occur more than once i only want the most recent one.

```
lst = [(587,"2015-01-01"),
        (625,"2011-12-01"),
        (587,"1998-05-01")]
```

I want this:

```
list2 = [(587,"2015-01-01"),
        ("625,2011-12-01"),]
```

One of the tuples look like:

```
(2, 14, 58875, 1, datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 1, 0, 0), u'RB', u'SYSTEM', datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 9, 7, 38), u'SYSTEM', datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 9, 7, 38))
```

The ID field has index 2 and date field index 4

Comment: Don't call your variables `list`: `list()` is a list constructor.

Comment: Is the order of the tuple elements in the list of importance? If not, you could migrate the list to dictionary, and when adding new dictionary key-value pairs, simply check if a pair already exist for the given key, and update the value in case the existing date is older than the one of the new pair.

Comment: the order is not important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict()` with an empty string as the default value:

```
lst = [(587,'2015-01-01'),
       (625,'2011-12-01'),
       (587,'1998-05-01')]

from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(lambda: "")

for k, v in lst:
    if result[k] < v:
        result[k] = v

list(result.items())
# [(625, '2011-12-01'), (587, '2015-01-01')]
```

---

If the elements in each tuple are too many to unpack as above, you can capture the tuple with a single variable and then use index to access it, for instance:

```
for x in lst: 
    if result[x[0]] < x[1]: 
        result[x[0]] = x[1]

list(result.items())
# [(625, '2011-12-01'), (587, '2015-01-01')]
```

Comment: Neat with the default value! Maybe worth mentioning (at least here in a comment) that it's possible that the OP needn't really return to the list data structure; it might be appropriate simply using a dictionary (also easing updating when new KV pairs arrive), as the (non-ordered) dictionary items can still be readily traversed over using `.items()` (/ `.iteriterms`).

Comment: My tuples actually look like (value,ID,value,value,date,value,...), can i use indexes in the for k,v, like k[1], v[4]?

Comment: In this case there are too many values to unpack the tuple in this manner. You can use a single variable and then index it. `for x in lst: if result[x[1]] < x[4]: result[x[1]] = x[4]` for instance.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand. Could you add this code to your answer?

Comment: Edited the answer with a different method, see the update.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.groupby` to group your tuples by the first element, then select the last element from each group:

```
groups = itertools.groupby(sorted(lst), lambda x:x[0])
[(list(x[1])[-1]) for x in groups]
# [(587, '2015-01-01'), (625, '2011-12-01')]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any library, this should work:

```
list2=[]

for i in list1:
    if i[0] not in [j[0] for j in list2]:
        list2.append(i)
    else: 
      for k in range(len(list2)):
        if i[0] == list2[k][0] and i[1] > list2[k][1]:
            list2[k] = i
```

Thus, if the ID is not in `list2`, it will append the touple, while if it is and the `i` date value is higher than the one in `list2`, it will replace it.

If your touples have other values, then just adapt it for your ID and date positions. For the case (value,ID,value,value,date,value,...) it would be:

```
list2=[]

for i in list1:
    if i[1] not in [j[1] for j in list2]:
        list2.append(i)
    else: 
      for k in range(len(list2)):
        if i[1] == list2[k][1] and i[4] > list2[k][4]:
            list2[k] = i
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: I get syntax error at this line: list2.append((i[0], max(i[1], [j[1] if j[0]==i[0] for j in list2][0])))

Comment: The max() wasn't appropiate, my mistake. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

An approach is using [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) like below:

```
my_list = [(587, '2015-01-01'),
        (625, '2011-12-01'),
        (587, '1998-05-01')]

my_keys = set(item[0] for item in my_list)  # to eliminate duplicates

res_list = []
for key in my_keys:
    res_list.append(filter(lambda item: item[0] == key, my_list)[0])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res_list
[(625, '2011-12-01'), (587, '2015-01-01')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

list = [(587,"2015-01-01"),
        (625,"2011-12-01"),
        (587,"1998-05-01")]

listsort = sorted([(e[0], datetime.strptime(e[1], "%Y-%m-%d")) for e in list])[::]
listfilter = sorted([(k, datetime.strftime(v, "%Y-%m-%d")) for k,v in dict(listsort).iteritems()])
print listfilter
```

Output

```
[(587, '2015-01-01'),
 (625, '2011-12-01')]
```